# PowerShell pointing the site to new location.

Tags: powershell, iis

I can get the current location as

```
#Connect to webserver1 or webserver2 to find the current location of site, this depends upon powershell remoting being enabled
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName

    Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration}
    Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Set-Location IIS:\}
    $CurrentLocation = Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Get-WebFilePath 'IIS:\Sites\Staging'}

    $LogMessage = "Staging site currently located at: " + $CurrentLocation
    write-host "##teamcity[message text='$LogMessage']"
```

I have posted my changes to

```
$dirname = "\\" + $ServerName + "\d$\inetpub\Staging\Mvc-" + $today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

How can i set this new location to be the site location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```powershell
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName
$dirname = "\\" + $ServerName + "\d$\inetpub\Staging\Mvc-" + $today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock{
    param($dirname)
    Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration 
    Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Staging' -Name physicalPath -Value $dirname        
}  -ArgumentList $dirname
```

Comment: This resulted in the following error. looks like the issue is Physicalpath.

Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the
[08:24:28] value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
[08:24:28] + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], PSArgum
[08:24:28] entNullException
[08:24:28] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Se
[08:24:28] tItemPropertyCommand

Comment: Try the amended answer.

Comment: This time it is this error: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
[08:49:18]At C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\CopyBuildOutpu
[08:49:18]tToStagingServers.ps1:80 char:9
[08:49:18]+ } - <<<< ArgumentList $dirname
[08:49:18] + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
[08:49:18] ception
[08:49:18] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Comment: This error looks like part of a larger script. Run the above code manually from a clean PS consoel and this will help you work out where is the problem(you will of course need to init `$ServerName` and `$today` vars). You can also add `Write-Host "Dirname is $dirname"` below `param($dirname)` to verify the path is getting passed correctly.

Comment: Your script only needed the -ScriptBlock as Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock